# ggplot throwing an error in weird circumstances

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to run this following code:

```
p <- ggplot(data=cuernavaca.map, aes(long, lat, group=group))
p + geom_polygon(size=0.1, aes(fill=pobtot)) + coord_equal() + facet_wrap(~nombre_municipio,scales="free") + coord_equal()  + scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue", high="red", midpoint=mean(cuernavaca.map$pobtot, na.rm=TRUE))+ tema.mapas + ggtitle("Cuervaca y Zona metropolitana\nPoblación Total") + labs(fill="Población total")
```

but I got this error:

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval

The object `cuernavaca.map` is a fortified `SpatialDataFrame`.

The weird thing is that this only happens in one machine (Ubuntu 13.04, RStudio 0.97.551, R 3.0.1) when I execute the `knit2html` or I hit the button `knit HTML`, If I execute the lines of code in the console (inside RStudio) everything works (I mean, the plot is done), If I cut and paste that code in other `.Rmd file` it works and If I execute it in another Ubuntu box (same specs as above) or MacOS X, it works!

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

As is written in the comments, the problem seems to be the order of the unnamed parameters, so I change the code to this:

```
ggplot(data = cuernavaca.map) + 
geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, colour = NA, fill = pobtot)) +
coord_equal() + 
facet_wrap(~nombre_municipio, scales = "free") + 
scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", midpoint = mean(cuernavaca.map$pobtot, 
na.rm = TRUE)) + 
tema.mapas + 
ggtitle("Cuervaca y Zona metropolitana\nPoblación Total") + 
labs(fill = "Población total")
```

And know is everything working ... almost.

If you see the code I remove the `size` parameter in the `geom_polygon` and I set the `colour` to `NA`, I made that, not for aesthetics reasons, but because, that parameters are not working: the line width of the polygon gets enormous and the color is just ignored, sometimes gets light red, in others it just disappears...

As a funny thing, the plots below this one, are working now, too, but guess what? The code is the following:

```
ggplot(legend = FALSE) + 
geom_polygon(data = cuernavaca.map, size = 0.1, aes(long, 
lat, group = group, colour = "grey80", fill = ind_vul)) + 
scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", midpoint = mean(cuernavaca.map$ind_vul, na.rm = TRUE)) + 
geom_point(data = puntos.df, aes(as.numeric(long), as.numeric(lat), colour = geografico), size = 2) +
facet_wrap(~municipio, scales = "free") + 
tema.mapas +  
labs(fill = "Índice de vulnerabilidad")
```

`puntos.df` is a `data.frame` with latitude and longitude, so no big deal, but not how the `size` parameters is out of the `aes` and is working (I am not getting a error of "not know how to deal with a numeric... blah blah")

Could be a memory issue?

Comment: I reinstalled  another computer with Ubuntu 13.04, and everything goes fine until I installed RStudio. Maybe the problem is related with the fact that in Ubuntu 13.04 you must force the installation of `libjpeg62` in order to install Rstudio, what do you think?

Comment: I think that I found some light, it has to do with the order of parameters in the function: if I change to this code (i.e. specifying the `mapping=`) `geom_polygon(size = 0,1, 
    mapping = aes(fill = pobtot.bin))`, the eror goes away, but now I got this one: `Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric` , So, still no solution :(

Comment: The last error is related with the `size`parameter outside the `aes`, but see the edit above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is told in the edit, the answer was using named parameters:

```
ggplot(data = cuernavaca.map) + 
geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, colour = NA, fill = pobtot)) +
coord_equal() + 
facet_wrap(~nombre_municipio, scales = "free") + 
scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", midpoint = mean(cuernavaca.map$pobtot, na.rm = TRUE)) +
```

There are some unanswered questions, but I posted a new one in: [ggplot map with points: size, colour, legend, aesthetics problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657920/ggplot-map-with-points-size-colour-legend-aesthetics-problems?lq=1)