# ggplot map with points: size, colour, legend, aesthetics problems

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this piece of code:

```
ggplot(legend = FALSE) + 
geom_polygon(data = map.df, size = 0.1, aes(long, lat, group = group, colour = "grey80", fill = ind_vul)) + 
scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", midpoint = mean(map.df$ind_vul, na.rm = TRUE)) + 
geom_point(data = puntos.df, aes(as.numeric(long), as.numeric(lat), colour = geografico), size = 2) +
facet_wrap(~municipio, scales = "free") + 
tema.mapas
```

And I found several problems (obviously related to my ignorance of this topic), the problems are the following (all related, see [ggplot throwing an error in weird circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631895/ggplot-throwing-an-error-in-weird-circumstances)):

- The size parameter in `geom_polygon` is working oddly, outside of the `aes` has no effect and inside of it is ignored, if there is no a `colour` parameter.
- The `colour` parameter is ignored (again in `geom_polygon`) in the code above saids `colour="grey80"` but the contour line of the polygon is in another colour and the "grey80" appears as legend of the points!

Comment: since `colour='grey80'` and `size=0.1` are not asking for a column of your `map.df` they should be outside of the `aes` call.  Without some sample data, that is about all the help I can give since I cannot see your error, see your data or work toward a solution.

Comment: Justin is right - in other words, when `color` is inside `aes`, `ggplot` thinks you're telling it to base the color of the plot on some column in your data. There's no column called `"grey80"`, so it's just making up a color. Outside of `aes`, `color` will look for a color that is named `grey80`.

Comment: You both are absolutely right! Some one want to post it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `colour='grey80'` and `size=0.1` are not asking for a column of your `map.df` they should be outside of the `aes` call. In other words, when `colour` is inside `aes`, ggplot thinks you're telling it to base the color of the plot on some column in your data, or if given a literal string like you have here, to create a mapping between that string and some entry in the usual color palette. Mapping an aesthetic to a literal string can be a useful technique in some cases, but is different than setting the aesthetic to a value. Outside of `aes`, color will look for a color that is named `"grey80"` and will use that specific color.

[adapted from comments and expanded slightly]